# Delayed evaluation of template type function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I read "The C++ Programming language 4th edition, 1st printing, by Bjarne Stroustrup" book (from Amazon.com).
Page 785.
Stroustrup is explaining how he can eliminate explicit writing of "**::type**", when using "**std::conditional** + **std::make_unsigned**", using "**type aliases**" (keyword "using"). But that using "type aliases" on "**std::conditional** + **std::make_unsigned**" is causing compile errors. 
By now everything is as it should be. And he goes on to show how to elimintate these compile errors using "delayed evaluation of template type function".

The question is on the line `Atype<make_unsigned<string>` and `myType2<string> ...`.

I used g++ 4.8.2.

### Compile:

### g++ -std=c++1y test45.cpp -o a

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>  // for typeid(...)
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct ErrIndicator {
   typedef ErrIndicator<T> type;
};

template<bool C, class T, class F>
using Conditional = typename conditional<C,T,F>::type;

template<typename T>
using Make_unsigned = typename make_unsigned<T>::type;

template<template<typename ...> class F, typename... Args>
using Delay = F<Args ...>;

template<class T>
using myType1 = Conditional<is_integral<T>::value,
    Make_unsigned<T>,
    ErrIndicator<T>
    >;

template<class T> 
    using myType2 = Conditional<is_integral<T>::value,
    Delay<Make_unsigned, T>,   // delayed evaluation
    ErrIndicator<T>
    >;

template<class T>
    using myType4 = Conditional<is_integral<T>::value,
    make_unsigned<T>,
    ErrIndicator<T>
    >;

template<typename T>
class Atype {}; 

template<typename T>
void func1(T &ia /* output param */) {
  cout << "unsigned integral type" << endl;
  ia = 4;  // "unsigned integral type" computation
}

template<typename T>
void func1(ErrIndicator<T> &) {
  cout << "non integral type: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

int main() {
  myType1<int> var1a; // OK
  // myType1<string> var1b; // Error; The book says error
  //                    // should occur here. Here I understand.
  myType2<int> var2a; // OK
  // myType2<string> var2b; // Error - why?. Maybe I didn't get it,
  //                      // but I understand the book as no
  //                      // error should occur here.
  //                      // @DyP answered it.
  Atype<make_unsigned<string> > var3;  // OK here, look below at @DyP
  //                             // for "foo, bar, X" why
  //                        // make_unsigned<string> is not an error here.
  // make_unsigned<string> var6; // Error
  // Atype<make_unsigned<string>::type > var4;  // Error
  Atype<make_unsigned<int>::type > var5;  // OK
  //-------------
  myType4<string>::type var7;    // Look below for "myType3", where @Yakk
  //                          // obviates the necessity to write "::type".
  // rsl7 = 1:
  cout << "rsl7 = " << is_same<decltype(var7), ErrIndicator<string> >::value << endl; 
  func1(var7);  // "non integral type" overload of func1()
  //---------
  myType4<int>::type var8;
  // rsl8 = 1:
  cout << "rsl8 = " << is_same<decltype(var8), unsigned int>::value << endl; 
  func1(var8);  // "unsigned integral type" overload of func1()
}
```

Comment: The error for string *should* be an error. `make_unsigned` requires its template argument to be of integral, but not `bool` type. As I understand it, it doesn't care that you don't use the nested `type`.

Comment: What do you think `Delay` is doing?  And what quote from the book makes you think that?  I mean, delayed evaluation could help, but what makes you think `Delay` does that?

Comment: @Yakk I think it's supposed to delay the evaluation of the metafunction `Make_unsigned` until it has been checked that the type is integral.

Comment: @DyP sure, but other than its name, why would it do so?

Comment: @Yakk Stroustrup introduces a `conditional< is_integral<T>::value, make_unsigned<T>, Error<T> >::type` and talks about that using this instead of `typename make_unsigned<T>::type` would prevent a compile-time error.

Comment: In the book: We can use a Delay type function to delay evaluation of a type function until its use. If it is integral then we will have integral otherwise ErrIndicator.

Comment: Stroustrup says: one way is to use `...::type` and the other way is to use Delay. Otherwise using type aliases will cause, in this case, compile error.

Comment: Why would Stroustrup write about `Delay` ? `myType1` in the exmaple crashes the same way as `myType2`. I have a feeling he introduced `Delay` as a way to compile the program without error. But ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Stroustrup intents to delay the access to `make_unsigned<T>::type`, because this nested type isn't defined for non-integral types. However, using an alias template seems not to be enough for clang++ and g++: They resolve `Delay<Make_unsigned,T>` directly to `Make_unsigned<T>`, and this to `make_unsigned<T>::type`.

The whole example is:

```
template<typename C, typename T, typename F>
using Conditional = typename std::conditional<C,T,F>::type;

template<typename T>
using Make_unsigned = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;

// the example
Conditional<
  is_integral<T>::value,
  Delay<Make_unsigned,T>,
  Error<T>
>

// "The implementation of a perfect `Delay` function is nontrivial,
//  but for many uses this will do:"
template<template<typename...> class F, typename... Args>
using Delay = F<Args...>;
```

---

The question is of course, when is `Delay<Make_Unsigned,T>` resolved? For class templates (not alias templates), they're only instantiated implicitly when a complete object type is required or the semantics of the program are affected. Consider:

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct foo
{
    static_assert(is_same<T, void>{}, "!");
};

template<class X>
struct bar
{
    // without the line below, no error!
    //X x;
};

int main()
{
    bar<foo<int>> b;
}
```

This however is not the case for alias templates. They're substituted [temp.alias]/2

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type
>   obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias
>   template.

IMHO, this suggests that in the example above, `Delay<Make_unsigned,T>` is equivalent to `make_unsigned<T>::type`, which *will* instantiate `make_unsigned<string>::type` and cause a compile-time error.

Comment: Which then would imply that you cannot write such a `Delay` metafunction: You had to use a class template, and that requires a nested typedef `type` (or inheritance, which leads to other problems). So you could write a `delay` (which serves no purpose), but not a `Delay`.

Comment: So what exactly is Stroustrup meaning by his Delay ? What is the use of the Delay ? The whole paragraph in the book is about this delay thing.

Comment: @vlakov I don't think the whole paragraph is about `Delay`. It is about not being able to use `Make_unsigned<T>` because that would be ill-formed. You have to select between `make_unsigned<T>` and `Error<T>` and *then* access the result's `::type`. He then proposes *instead* of doing that to delay access to `make_unsigned<T>::type`, but I don't think this can work via an alias template.

Comment: @vlakov I think instead of `Delay`, you can use a `conditional_apply` either as suggested by Yakk, or something like `template<bool C, class T, class F>
using Conditional_apply = typename conditional<C,T,F>::type::type;` which is to be used like `Conditional_apply<is_integral<T>::value, make_unsigned<T>, Error<T>>`.

Comment: He writes about hiding the `::type`. He offers 2 alternatives. The 1. alternative where he explicitly uses `::type` compiles without error. The second alternative is `Delay`. But this alternative fails. Therefore `Delay` is a mistake in the book ?

Comment: @vlakov Either it's a mistake in the book, or in the C++ Standard, or in both compilers ;) Whatever it is, I think you could send Bjarne Stroustrup an email, as it isn't listed in the [errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html).

Comment: DyP, remove the body of `foo`?  That should fail without `X x` imstance.  The problem seems to be that you need a type, and `make_unsigned<string>` is not a type.

Comment: @Yakk You mean `template<class T>
struct foo;`? I don't see why that should fail, it's just an incomplete type. -- Why isn't `make_unsigned<string>` a type? I agree that it could be UB to write `make_unsigned<string>`, but to make that ill-formed you'd need another defaulted template-parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<bool, template<typename...>class Lhs, template<typename...>class Rhs, typename... Ts>
struct conditional_apply {
  typedef Lhs<Ts...> type;
};
template<template<typename...>class Lhs, template<typename...>class Rhs, typename...Ts>
struct conditional_apply<false, Lhs, Rhs, Ts...> {
  typedef Rhs<Ts...> type;
};
template<bool b, template<typename...>class Lhs, template<typename...>class Rhs, typename... Ts>
using Conditional_apply=typename conditional_apply<b, Lhs, Rhs, Ts...>::type;

template<class T> using myType3 = Conditional_apply<is_integral<T>::value, Make_unsigned, ErrIndicator, T >;
```

should do actual delayed application of `template`s on `T`, barring typos (on phone).